# How to populate random data coming from websocket into table using angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket

I have some data that I am manipulating into a table using loop.Here Data will come one by one same like we are using in websocket. I am using websocket in my project for that to populate the data which comes one by one.Data should be populate into table one by one as similar to its coming randomly. Here do I need to hold the data and push one by one, or it will manupulate randomly automatically into the table.If I need to hold or push,how to do that can anyone please help me. Here is the sample code.

### home.component.html

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="2">
 <tr *ngFor = "let x of mySocketData">
 <td>{{x.id}}</td>
 <td>{{x.name}}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
statusdata: any;
closeResult: string;
registerForm: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
webSocketEndPoint: string = 'http://localhost:8080/ws';
topic: string = "/topic/greetings";
stompClient: any;
mySocketData:any;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Initialize WebSocket Connection");
        let ws = new SockJS(this.webSocketEndPoint);
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
        const _this = this;
        _this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            _this.stompClient.subscribe(_this.topic, function (sdkEvent) {
                this.mySocketData = sdkEvent;
               console.log(this.mySocketData);//[{"id":1,"name":"cat"},{"id":2,"name":"arctichare"},{"id":3,"name":"baboon"}]
            });
            //_this.stompClient.reconnect_delay = 2000;
        });

  }

  }
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "sampleproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.4.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

### index.html

```
<script>
      var global = window; // fix global is undefined in socketjs-client
  </script>
```

Comment: Where is your websocket code? At least try to edit the question with what you've tried so far. (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Comment: I have edited also created a demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqlxkd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts